# strpos - user agent partial matching

Tags: php, string-matching, strpos

I am trying to detect 2 different phones based on their user agents.

I used strpos but my code is outputting "other phone" on both phones.

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 


$phone1 = "SM-G900F";
$phone2 = "GT-I9505";


if(strpos($phone1,$ua)!==false){
 echo "gs 5";
 }

elseif (strpos($phone2,$ua)!==false){
 echo "gs 4";
} else {
  echo "other phone";
}
```

Comment: What is the output of: `echo $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your arguments are backwards, the syntax is

```
strpos($haystack, $needle)
```

You're basically saying `is 'Argle bargle Foo SM-G900F Bar Baz' contained in the string 'SM-G900F'`, for which the answer is obviously "NO".

Try

```
if(strpos($ua, $phone1)!==false){
```

instead.

Comment: This worked but my else no longer works - if i open the url on a phone that is not phone1 and phone2, it no longer outputs "other phone"

Comment: so start debugging: output the UA you're testing, see what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, swap the variables inside strpos function for this logic to work,

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 


$phone1 = "SM-G900F";
$phone2 = "GT-I9505";


if(strpos($ua,$phone1)!==false){
 echo "gs 5";
 }

elseif (strpos($ua,$phone2)!==false){
 echo "gs 4";
} else {
  echo "other phone";
}
```

Comment: works but my else part no longer works - "other phone" does not appear when script is opened on a device with different UA.